# Parse : Xcode 6.3.1 running on OS X El Capitan Error "cannot load module parse as parse"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, parse-platform

Error in Xcode 6.3.1
OS X El Capitan-Swift

> ERROR : **Cannot load module parse as parse**

[image]

[image]
Bridging header File

## import "Parse/Parse.h"

Comment: Does it work with a lowercase import statement, like `import parse`? Are you including the Parse framework/module your own project which is titled... "parse"? I wonder if your own project's module name is overriding/preventing Xcode from locating any differently-cased modules. Can you try creating a new project with a different name?

Comment: Header > import "Parse/Parse.h"  >AppDelegate Parse nor parse are working

Answer (score 0):

Just add [Bridging-Header.h](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/) in your project.

And you can add this code into it:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Hope it will help.